# indicator-cpufreq frequency lost after suspension/hibernation

Tags: suspend, indicator, cpu, hibernate, cpufreq

As the title, I'm using `indicator-cpufreq` to set the frequency of the CPU. It's really useful when you are on battery and you want to save some power.
However, when I wake the laptop after a suspension or hibernation, the CPU frequency is automatically set to the maximum possible (i.e. my previous settings were lost).

How can I avoid that?